# Issues with conversion of .mht to .pdf files and clearing memory

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am currently using VBA to loop through some .msg Outlook files and convert them to .pdfs through a mid-step .mht conversion. Code will be pasted below. Currently, I am getting the correct conversion about 40% of the time. Correct conversion meaning the folder in question will, after running this macro, have a correct .pdf and .mht version of the .msg file.

However, the other 60% of the time, the conversion gets stuck in Word going from .mht to .pdf. Everything just hangs and I have to end the Word.exe process. That is issue #1. Perhaps tied to this issue, whenever this VBA converts the file successfully from .msg to .mht to .pdf, I am also left with the ghost(s) of previous .mht files I have converted, even if they're not in the folder. These are files that have very limited info in typewriter type font and whose filenames begin with "~$ NAME CUTOFF HERE". I have tried to Set my object to Nothing before AND after running my code to try and release the memory, but it still getting caught up. Photo below as well to help explain. Does anyone have any thoughts on what is going on?

The conversion from .msg to .mht works like a charm every time.

Please note, I am only posting the relevant code. Everything else above this ElseIf statement is converting various other filetypes to .pdf (namely .doc*, .xls*, and .ppt*).

I previously used a variation of this, but wanted to a. speed up the process and b. not be beholden to having to click "save" every time. [link here.](https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/saveaspdf.htm)

[Image of Ghost Files - Most recent run of code below with that one .msg file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzC3P.png)

```
'Above this is irrelevant other If statement
      ElseIf (oFile) Like ("*.msg") Then

                Dim newName4 As String
                newName4 = Replace(oFile.path, ".msg", ".pdf")
                newName4 = Replace(newName4, ".msg", ".pdf")
                Dim strHTML As String

                Dim objOL As Object
                Dim Msg As Object
                Dim Dms2 As Object
                Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
                Set Msg = objOL.Session.OpenSharedItem(oFile.path)

                strHTML = Left(oFile.path, InStrRev(oFile.path, Chr(46))) & "mht"

                With Msg
                    .SaveAs strHTML, olMHTML
                    .Close olDiscard
                End With

            ElseIf (oFile) Like ("*.mht") Then

                Dim newName5 As String
                newName5 = Replace(oFile.path, ".mht", ".pdf")
                newName5 = Replace(newName5, ".mht", ".pdf")

                Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
                Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document

                Set wrdDoc = Nothing
                Set wrdApp = Nothing

                Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
                Dim x As Integer
                x = 1
                wrdApp.Documents.Open Filename:=oFile.path, Visible:=False
                'Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Item(x)

                wrdApp.Documents.Item(x).ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=newName5 _
                        , ExportFormat:= _
                        wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
                        wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=0, To:=0, _
                        Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
                        CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
                        BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False

                wrdApp.Documents.Item(x).Close
                wrdApp.Quit

                Set wrdDoc = Nothing
                Set wrdApp = Nothing

            End If

        Next oFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question!

```
            ElseIf (oFile) Like ("*.msg") Then

                Dim newName4 As String
                newName4 = Replace(oFile.path, ".msg", ".pdf")
                newName4 = Replace(newName4, ".msg", ".pdf")
                Dim strHTML As String

                Dim objOL As Object
                Dim Msg As Object
                Dim Dms2 As Object
                Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
                Set Msg = objOL.Session.OpenSharedItem(oFile.path)

                strHTML = Left(oFile.path, InStrRev(oFile.path, Chr(46))) & "mht"

                With Msg
                    .SaveAs strHTML, olMHTML
                    .Close olDiscard
                End With

                On Error GoTo WordAppQuit
                Dim newName5 As String
                newName5 = Replace(strHTML, ".mht", ".pdf")
                newName5 = Replace(newName5, ".mht", ".pdf")
                Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
                Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
                Set wrdDoc = Nothing
                Set wrdApp = Nothing

                Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
                Dim x As Integer
                x = 1
                wrdApp.Documents.Open Filename:=(strHTML)
                'Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Item(x)

                wrdApp.Documents.Item(x).ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=newName5 _
                        , ExportFormat:= _
                        wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
                        wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=0, To:=0, _
                        Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
                        CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
                        BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
WordAppQuit:
                wrdApp.Documents.Item(x).Close
                wrdApp.Quit

                Set wrdDoc = Nothing
                Set wrdApp = Nothing

                newName5 = ""
```